# Is there a way I can increase performance rendering 1000+ cards of data onto a single page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, redux, jsx

My goal is to take a bunch of information from my props and set it into cards to be displayed on a single page. I cannot use pagination. I've noticed the more information I display the worse the page gets. For example when I render 1200 cards about cars, it lags heavily. Then when I add pictures to those cards, my webpage pretty much crashes.

I understand maybe the page has way too many dom elements and data in them; how can I fix this in React?

I have looked into other libraries like react-visualized where the data is rendered as you scroll instead of all at once on the dom. Some of them aren't kept up with and I thought I'd ask before I went down that road.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { actionCreators } from '../../store/landing';
    import { Card } from 'reactstrap';

    class Car extends Component {
        state = {
            cardData: [],
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            this.ensureDataFetched();
        }

        ensureDataFetched() {
            this.props.getCardData();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                    <div>                                
                       {this.props.landingData.length === 0 ? null :
                           this.props.carData.map((car, cardId) => {
                                    <Card key={carId}>{car.title}</Card>
                             })
                       }
                     </div>                       
            );
        }
    }

    export default connect(
        state => state.car,
        dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    )(Car);
```

Comment: Not a surprise, hitting the DOM on each data instance forces it to reflow/render the DOM each time and will get worse as it scales up.

Comment: surly you want to add pagination for 1ks of results anyway despite what plug and play libs there is, unmaintained or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to display the cards, but I'm pretty sure the what you need it a virtualized list or some kind of virtualized structure.

You can use [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

There is alot of examples in the docs, take a look at the[`List`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md) component.